# Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored isn't focusable per default

Tags: android

Historically Android buttons where per default always focusable, at least they had a state list.
If you now use the style `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`-> `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`--> `android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored` focusable isn't defined:

```
<!-- Bordered ink button -->
<style name="Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_default_material</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="stateListAnimator">@anim/button_state_list_anim_material</item>
    <item name="focusable">true</item>
    <item name="clickable">true</item>
    <item name="gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>

<!-- Colored bordered ink button -->
<style name="Widget.Material.Button.Colored">
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_colored_material</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored</item>
</style>
```

So, using Widget.Material.Button.Colored you won't get navigation focus when navigating with a keyboard, you need to add a custom style that extends this style and use following for it to work:

```
<item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
```

Is there a reasson why this property is not set by default anymore?

Comment: `Widget.Material.Button.Colored` inherits from `Widget.Material.Button`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the implicit inheritance! Then I'm confused why navigation focus only works using the foreground property.